# Using appendChildren to add buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work with the following code.  I'm trying to change the buttons to display...

1-5  5-10  10-15  15-20    etc.

```
appendChildren(buttons, pages.map(
    function (page, index) {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.addEventListener("click", display);
        button.innerHTML = (index + 1) + "-" + (index + 5);
        return button;

        function display() {
            displayPage(page);
        }
    })
);
```

Here's the code working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hypermiler/P3v7q/)   Just not the way I need it to work.

Comment: You seem to be missing document.getElementById('pageButtons').appendChild(button); line, yet when I checked your fiddle it was showing(?). Seems that your code is also dropping the first and last string characters for each in array. Not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: So, originally, the code just used:  button.innerHTML=index+1.  I added the new part trying to get it to do what I want.

Comment: Please explain "not the way I need it to work". Doesn't it add the buttons? Are the labels wrong? Wrong order?…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of math.

This line in your code:

```
button.innerHTML = (index + 1) + "-" + (index + 5);
```

Should read:

```
button.innerHTML = ((index * 5) + 1) + "-" + ((index * 5) + 5);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98LFf/)